# Smallest distribution of points with genuinely different clusterings

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics, algorithms

An [hierarchical clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) algorithm for (finite) sets of points in a given metric space is essentially determined by its [linkage criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Linkage_criteria), which defines the distance between arbitrary (finite) *sets* of points with respect to a given distance between *single* points.

The corresponding Wikipedia page exhibits a simple [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Example_for_Agglomerative_Clustering) of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but all the linkage criteria which are considered seem to provide the same [dendrogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram) (with respect to Euclidean distance).

So I am looking for

> **a smallest distribution of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with property *P***

where property ***P*** means that each of the following linkage criteria (with respect to Euclidean distance) yields a genuinely different result:

- [complete linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_linkage_clustering)
- [single linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering)
- [average linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPGMA)
- [centroid linkage](http://www.stanford.edu/~maureenh/quals/html/ml/node78.html)
- [minimum energy linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_distance)

I am looking for an answer like that for

> **a smallest asymmetric non-trivial graph**

which is one of the following:

[image]

[from [Asymmetric graphs](http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1963-04.pdf) by P. Erdös and A. Renyi]